# renaming a data set script

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have  imported a file using the following code. I have set the pathway for the file to be used.

```
library(tidyverse)
election data <- read_csv(file = "NSW_primaries.csv", col_names = TRUE)
view(election data)
```

How do I convert the data set from a long to wide format, and store the new format under a new name?

I really am a newbie.

I am also concerned my question is not well worded.

Any advice (please don't make fun of me if my data grammar is off)

I tried

```
rename.file(election_data, NSW_polls)
```

and get the error

```
could not find function "rename.file"
```

Comment: You can't use spaces in the names you give to objects. `election data` will result in an error, so the convention is to use the `_` as spaces - so use something like `election_data` instead. To save an object into a different name, you just assign it `my_obj2 <- fun(my_obj)`. To save a data frame back to disk in CSV format, use `write_csv()` from the readr package. To change a data from long to wide, use `pivot_wider()` from the tidyr package. See here for more info, or run `?write_csv` and `?pivot_wider` to access those functions help pages. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(election_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(election_data, 20))`. Also, it's `file.rename`.

Comment: thank you so much for replying. I really don't know what to do with pivot_wider(). We have been given data from a .csv file and we need to go from long to wide. We also need to split the data i.e. duration to duration _1, duration_2.  The example we have been given is  short_form <- long_form %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "time_point", values_from = "STAI_score")